# Do I have to call EasyTracker.getInstance(this); everytime I need the easyTracker?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Do I have to call `EasyTracker.getInstance(this);` everytime I need the tracker or can I only initialize in `onCreate()` and from then on store it as a private field like this?

```
public class AndroidStarter extends Activity   
{
    private EasyTracker easyTracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        easyTracker.activityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        easyTracker.activityStop(this); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either way.

The advantage of your way is that you don't have to call getInstance(). This might be very very very slightly faster.

The advantage of calling `getInstance()` each time is that if the Tracker isn't getting used for a while because you're in the same Activity for a while, the Tracker could get garbage collected to free up memory.

Comment: well but I need to frequently retrieve my EasyTracker instance, so I wonder if it's ok to store it as a field and not to call that method everytime I need it.